# PHP cURL redirect to location is not working correctly

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send some values to a remote URL using curl. but the remote site redirects to another page which is causing me troubles.

for example, i send values from www.mywebsite.com to url www.domain.com/index.php, index.php redirects to fetch.php file, but the thing is it opens like this www.mywebsite.com/fetch.php which gives me 404 not found error because this file is on remote site not mine. how can i fix this

this is the code that i'm using

```
$postfields = "link=xxxxxx";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'domain.com/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'rap.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: If it redirects to `fetch.php`, why don't you curl that page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php#constant.curlopt-followlocation)  option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: yes i did that as well, it redirects to www.mydomain.com/newpage.php instead of the www.remotedomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com/index.php');
```

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'domain.com/index.php');
```

Comment: you can set curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1) and for seeing result use >>echo $content

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first replicating the actions you want to take as a user.

I.e. visiting the URL and seeing how it works, i.e. how the flow of the data goes from 1 URL to the next etc. Then attempt to replicate that by posting the required data to the correct URL.

It could also be that the first URL is checking the referrer, to ensure that page is not being abused.